# Stack overflow into opcode PUSH (ASM)

Tags: assembly, stack, overflow, push, opcode

I'm trying to understand asm and stack overflow via https://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/.
As I understood a regular stack overflow pushes beyond the **stack boundary** into RAM.
My question is what happens if the stack overflow pushes beyond **RAM boundaries**.

In the simulator if you have a program with the code:

```
PUSH 53 ; 53 or 0x35 is opcode for PUSH 
JMP 0 ; loop it
```

The program overwrites itself into pushing the stack beyond RAM, stack pointer goes to -1.
What would happen in a real scenario, real program?

Comment: That depends on circumstances, such as architecture and operating system. You normally get a fault and your process is terminated.

Comment: On an x86 you could never "push beyond __RAM boundaries__". The stack will happily wraparound in the available address space (64KB for real address mode, 4GB for protected mode). Results will be disastrous though!

Comment: stack is usually managed trough register "stack pointer" (or `sp` on many CPUs like Z80 or x86). When you push something on stack, it means you do `store value to [sp], sub sp,value_size`. And `sub reg,#n` usually simply wraps around, so subtracting `1` from `0` would fill `sp` with `0xFFFF` (considering 16b platform), and you would start again from top of 16b memory.

Answer (score 2):

A very nice definition from Wikipedia:

> In software, a stack overflow occurs if the call stack pointer exceeds
>   the stack bound. The call stack may consist of a limited amount of
>   address space, often determined at the start of the program. The size
>   of the call stack depends on many factors, including the programming
>   language, machine architecture, multi-threading, and amount of
>   available memory. When a program attempts to use more space than is
>   available on the call stack (that is, when it attempts to access
>   memory beyond the call stack's bounds, which is essentially a buffer
>   overflow), the stack is said to overflow, typically resulting in a
>   program crash.

The definition of what the stack bound is, how much memory the stack has is not some universal thing.  Some (old) processors have a built in 8 or 16 deep stack that we cant see only for return addresses, you function call too deep and you start overwriting addresses you may need later.

On a windows/linux/mac machine where you are in a virtual address space with protections from keeping you from wandering outside your allocated space, it is within the possible design solutions to allocate your stack as its own protected blob of ram (separate from program, data, and heap), and if you wander off the edge of that you get a memory fault as you would get if you try to do any data access with a virtual address you are not permitted to access.

There are no doubt many other interesting cases, but the normal ram based view of a program is at a lower address you have your program and some data, at the higher address you have a stack that grows downward, and the stuff in the middle is the heap essentially or some portion of that is defined as the heap to give you some amount of stack space.  Normally if you were to try to do what you described by endlessly pushing what would happen is the stack would grow downward filling with that value until it overwrites the loop you are executing, and depending on how the processor works it may still continue if fetching from cache, or it will try to execute the bytes you are filling the cache with and depending on what those are may or may not crash.  If it tries to execute those bytes then unless they are stack based it is no longer "filling" the cache with junk.

So a "stack overflow" on a lot of systems just means that your stack and heap or stack and program collided, the software is trying to use the same addresses for the stack and for data and depending on who is reading and writing when determines who gets bad data or uses bad return addresses, etc. Most likely resulting in a crash, but sometimes just horribly bad behavior.  You can very easily test this with a recursive function that you keep recursively calling until it crashes.

Comment: Your simulator thing and instruction set you are running may be special and may prevent you from doing this.  It is possible, it adds a lot of code, to have your toolchain and combination of libraries, etc, to prevent this collision, basically every time the stack is used it checks to see if it is digging into the defined heap.

Comment: I think valgrind can be used to not necessarily prevent a stack overflow, but by filling the memory and then at some point examining it they can see how deep the stack went or how high the heap went.